# Phonegap (or cordova) and requirejs

Tags: cordova, requirejs, require

I tried to load cordova.js or phonegap.js (with phonegapbuild) as an AMD module in the main.js in require.config like this:

```
cordova: 'cordova.js'
```

Should I include it in the shim ?

How can do you test it then? Can you use navigator.getPicture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem when trying to load cordova using requireJS.

It seems it won't work with cordova 2.2.0 (and maybe other versions).

You can read [my post about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233301/cordova-2-2-0-on-ios-requirejs-wont-load-cordova-correctly).

Hope this helps!