# Require.js issue loading both Google Maps and it's Richmarker extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps, requirejs, amd

I'm currently trying to load the Google Maps library and its extension, the [RichMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/), using require.js modules definitions and dependency handlers.

I've declared the paths to both the Google Maps module and the extension like following:

```
"gmaps": "modules/google_maps",
"richmarker": "vendor/google/maps/richmarker.min"
```

The google_maps module looking like

```
define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true'],
function(){
  return window.google.maps;
});
```

And finally, the module made to consume the google maps Library and the advancedMarker extension defined as follows:

```
define(['common', 'gmaps','jquery','jqueryui',  'bootstrap',"vendor/google/maps/clusterer.min", "tmp/clusteringData", "richmarker"],
function(common, gmaps){
```

Yet, the googlemap properly inits onload, but I get errors regarding the richmarker extension in  my console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined richmarker.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: RichMarker is not defined google.init.js:267
```

Where am am I doing it wrong ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `infobox.js` that strictly depends on Google Maps.

What I have done:

1. I've defined module `google` (instead of `gmaps`) that returns the whole google object (instead of single `maps` property)

   ```
   define('google', ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true'],
     function() {
       return window.google;
     });
   ```
2. I've defined dependency between `infobox` and `google` in RequireJS config file:

   ```
   paths: {
     google: 'ref/google',
     infobox: 'ref/infobox'
   },
   shim: {
     infobox: {
       deps: ['google']
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered the same question not long ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955963/1916258

I think you need to "shim" the google object.

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: 'js',
   paths: {
      gmaps: 'path/to/gmaps'
   },
   shim: {
      gmaps: {
         exports: 'google'
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me even when I am mapping to my local path without async.