# AppleTV and CommonJS or AMD (require.js)

Tags: module, requirejs, commonjs, apple-tv

Is there anyone who successfully used either `require.js` or one of the `commonJS` implementations in apple tv apps? I wanted to give a try to `require.js`, but spotted right away that `require.js` uses `window` object and maybe some other stuff that simply doesn't exist on apple tv. So maybe I should look for other options? How do you guys deal with modules? My predecessor just concatenated bunch of .js files and made a mess with literally tens of thousands lines of code. Incredibly messy.

upd: Still trying to make require.js work but apple tv won't let me have `data-main` attribute in `script` tag, I guess you can run require.config in the next script that loads right after

upd2: Doesn't work... apple tv doesn't have `window` object... Darn you Apple... I'll try to make changes to require.js file itself

No... definitely require.js not suited, even after major refactoring and changing browser specific stuff in the lib to ATV specific, still doesn't work. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova 2.4.0 or 2.5.0 or 2.6.0 and requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440529/cordova-2-4-0-or-2-5-0-or-2-6-0-and-requirejs)

Comment: What Cordova has to do with AppleTV? They are absolutely two different products. Implications of using javascript libraries on AppleTV specific to Apple TV and Apple TV only. I will explain that in more detailed post.

Comment: There is an intersection via [Airplay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346921/ios-airplay-plugin-using-cordova).

Comment: Paul, AppleTV is not even based on iOS. it uses proprietary javascript engine and xml instead of DOM. So as I said they're not related

Comment: [Airplay](https://developer.apple.com/airplay/) is an integration point between iOS and AppleTV which could be used as an alternative.

Comment: There are [many](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3245), [many](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5404), [many](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5517), [many](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4448), [many](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4215) mentions of the relationship.

Comment: Well, what are you talking about? Airplay integration in an iOS app deployed through Cordova? Then yes, but this question is NOT related neither to airplay nor to iOS. It is about TV Apps on Apple TV

Comment: >So maybe I should look for other options?